# Cassandra removing node and use it seperatel

Tags: cassandra

I have a few questions about Cassandra, waiting for suggestions from experts. Thank you.

1. I'm using 3 nodes with replication factor 3. And all nodes own %100 of data.

   ```
   [root@datab ~]# nodetool status mydatabase

   Datacenter: DC1
   ===============
   Status=Up/Down
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

   --  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID    Rack

   UN  192.168.1.1  11.83 GiB  8            100.0%            c0fb9cfc-b20a-4c65-93b6-8e14107cc411  r1

   UN  192.168.1.2  20.13 GiB  8            100.0%            dd940c60-9645-45ca-894d-f0af49a7bd83  r1

   UN  192.168.1.3  17.27 GiB  8            100.0%            3031587e-5354-4342-9ddc-e5696985fc8c  r1
   ```

I want to remove node 192.168.1.3 and use this server as separated for testing purpose, I mean I want to keep %100 of data till removing the node.

I tried to decommission, but I couldn't use as separated.

2. For example, I have a table with 100gb data in it and select all queries returning slower. This 3 nodes running on separated hardware (servers). If I add 10 nodes for each server with docker, it makes queries run faster?
3. For 3 node, what is the difference between having replication factor 2 and 3?  3 node with replication factor keeps %100 data, but whenever I alter replication factor to 2, data percentages are getting down in few seconds, with factor 2 if I lose one of server, do I lost any data?
4. Whats the proper step to remove 1 node from the dc1 ?

   - changing factor to 2 ?
   - removenode ID ?
   - or first remove node than change factor ?

Thank you !!